# htaccess RewriteRule works in tester, but not on live site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all subdomains except those I specify to a special url and append whatever was typed to the end of the request path. Here's my current htaccess in root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore

# Redirect www to main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect all subdomains except reserved subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|other|reserved|subs)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://other.example.com/path/%1 [L,R=302]

# Redirect all other HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works in [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) but the following url typed into a browser does not resolve:

```
https://unknown.example.com
```

I'm using Apache 2.4.57

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Increase your LogLevel, it will show you exactly what it is trying to do in the rewrite engine, in your error log file.

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't be a `$1` in this? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://other.example.com/path/%1 [L,R=302]`

Comment: What do you mean by "does not resolve"? This sounds like the error message a typical browser will generate, when the name resolution fails. So when a DNS entry for that host name is missing. Remember that you need a wildcard DNS entry if you want to receive requests to arbitrary host names inside your domain.

Comment: @arkascha this was the issue. Thank you! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, since you insist ...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the error message a typical browser will generate, when the name resolution fails. So when a DNS entry for that host name is missing. Remember that you need a wildcard DNS entry if you want to receive requests to arbitrary host names inside your domain.